# How can I Add onClick functionality to particular column in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, react-player

I have a datagrid in which there is one column named File_link. I want to add functionality to that field such that when user clicks that cell it should open react player and pass that cell value as url to react player. I have already created react player and datagrid.

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92OgA.png)
In the image there are two link. When user clicks on any of the link. Reactplayer should get that link as url value and open react player

```
<ReactPlayer
        ref={playerRef}
        width={"100%"}
        height={"100%"}
        url="xyz" -----> the value of the cell should be passed to this.
        muted={muted}
        playing={playing}
        volume={volume}
        playbackRate={playbackRate}
        onProgress={handleProgress}
      />
```

```
//data for table 
const datafortable = this.state.recordingdata1.map((mapvalue,index) => {
return{
id=index+1,
application:mapvalue.applicationname,
File_Link=<a target ="_blank" href={mapvalue.File_Link}></a>,
}
})


//data for column config
ColConfig=[
{
datakey:'id',
label:'id',
width:50,
dataType:'number';
},
{
datakey:'application',
label:'application',
width:50,
dataType:'string';
},
{
datakey:'File_Link',
label:'File_Link',
width:50,
dataType:'string';
}
]

//calling table
<Table 
fundColConfig=ColConfig
data={datafortable}
>

//datagrid in table.js
<DataFGrid
columns={this.props.fundColConfig}
keyFeildName="id"
data={this.state.data}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a URL in your component's this.state, change it with this.setState(), and when you include the player, write something like:

```
<ReactPlayer url={ this.state.url } /> 


  onClicked() {
   this.setState({url:event.target.value}
}

     const datafortable = this.state.recordingdata1.map((mapvalue,index) => {
return{
    id=index+1,
    application:mapvalue.applicationname,
    File_Link=<a target ="_blank" href={mapvalue.File_Link} onClick = {this.onClicked}></a>,
}
})
```

Comment: Hi. Chnage state will be done on onchange event or onclick events. How do I apply Onclick event on that cell click??

Comment: <div onClick={this.onClickHandler}></div>


 onClickHandler = (event) =>{
 this.setState({event.target.value}) 
 }

Comment: Please find the updated code in the question. I am not able to apply onclick in the filelink. Please advise. Also File_Link is an array